# Javascript generating random password not working

Tags: javascript, function, passwords

Just trying to make a random password generator and I'm not getting any output in my alert I'm using to test. Not getting any errors so I'm not sure what my mistake is.

```
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var getRandomNumber = function() {
    var num = parseInt$("num").value = "";
    var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

alert(text).toString());
};



var clearFields = function() {
    $("num").value = "";
    $("password").value = "";
    $("num").focus();
};



window.onload = function() {
    $("generate").onclick = getRandomNumber;
    $("clear").onclick = clearFields;
    $("num").focus();
};
```

Comment: Learn to use your debugger built into the browser

Answer (score 0):

You do have an error.

There is an extra `)` in this statement `alert(text).toString());`.